# Auto mount SD Card like in desktop version

Tags: server, mount, sd-card

I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04 and want to auto mount SD cards when inserting. This should be done in the way like the Ubuntu desktop versions do.

When inserting a SD card with the name "SD1" it should be mounted under /media/SD1

Comment: Have you ever figured this out?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.